# how to sign into google mail in one step

Tags: gmail

I only have gmail, but last week my mail opened with an extra step, by asking me to choose an account. I clicked on the gmail with my name on it, and then the password request came up. How do I eliminate this new step and go back to just the password request window? I only have one gmail account, so this is a mystery. Thanks. I'm afraid if I click on anything I won't be able to get into my mail.  Below shows the  new choices that I pasted in:

Choose an account
(NAME)@gmail.com       Signed out

Use another account

Remove an account

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below images:

## Step 1

Click the "Remove an account" button.

[image]

## Step 2

First press the minus sign and then the "Done" link

[image]